# Error when moving an item in a drag and drop list

Tags: javascript, list, drag-and-drop

I am working on a drag and drop list, I need that every time you try to move an item on the list ask if you really want to move it, if so, make the move, if not, return it to its initial position.

```
function handleDragEnd(e) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#f8c286",
        confirmButtonText: "Accept",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        html: true
    },
    function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            e.target.classList.remove('over');
            var start = $("#"+e.target.id).prev().attr('id');
            var end = $("#"+e.target.id).next().attr('id');
            Calculate(start,e.target.id,end,data);
            swal("Successfull","change made", "success");
        } else {
            this.ondragexit;
        }
    });
```

But I have errors in both cases, when it's affirmative, I get error in the remove
[image]

And when I don't want to move it, he lets me do it anyway.

How can it be corrected to work properly?

Could you help me, please?

Comment: in your case `e.target.classList` is undefined

Comment: But if I take that expression out of the swal function I can't be wrong, what could that be? @MichaelMishin

Comment: output to the console `console.log(e.target)` before `e.target.classList.remove('over');`